# Python Azure SDK: Using list_blobs to get more than 5.000 Results

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm having trouble with the Python Azure SDK and haven't found anything both on Stack Overflow and in the Msdn Forums.

I want to use Azure SDKs list_blobs() to get a list of blobs - there are more than 5.000 (which is the max_result).

If I take a look at the code in the SDK itself then I see the following:

```
    def list_blobs(self, container_name, prefix=None, marker=None,
                   maxresults=None, include=None, delimiter=None):
```

The description for 'Marker' being:

```
    marker:
        Optional. A string value that identifies the portion of the list
        to be returned with the next list operation. The operation returns
        a marker value within the response body if the list returned was
        not complete. The marker value may then be used in a subsequent
        call to request the next set of list items. The marker value is
        opaque to the client.
```

My problem is that I'm unaware on how to use the marker to get the next set of 5.000 results. If I try something like this:

```
    blobs = blobservice.list_blobs(target_container, prefix= prefix)            
    print(blobs.marker)
```

then the marker is always empty, which I assume is because list_blobs() already parses the blobs out of the response.

But if that is the case then how do I actually use the marker in a meaningful way?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but this actually is the first one that I didn't find an answer for, even after searching extensively.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDK returns the continuation token in a variable called `next_marker`. You should use that to get the next set of blobs. See the code below as an example. Here I'm listing 100 blobs from a container at a time:

```
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<accountname>', account_key='<accountkey>')
next_marker = None
while True:
    blobs = blob_service.list_blobs('<containername>', maxresults=100, marker=next_marker)
    next_marker = blobs.next_marker
    print(next_marker)
    print(len(blobs))
    if next_marker is None:
        break
print "done"
```

P.S. The code above throws an exception on the last iteration. Not sure why. But it should give you an idea.

Comment: Oh, it is 'next marker'! I actually feel pretty stupid now. How did you figure that out? Just so that I can make sure to solve my next problem on my own :)

Comment: Don't feel bad :) ... I ended up modifying the code here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/storage/__init__.py#L381 to see the properties returned. Not very obvious I must say. For future reference, you can look at the source code of the SDK here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python. HTH.

Comment: Ah, I see! I actually checked the source code for the list_blobs - function but I never had the idea of checking the parsing code >.< 

Anyway - thank you for the help!

Comment: In order to get rid of this error you need to change line `if next_marker is None:` to `if not next_marker:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AccountName, account_key=AccountKey)
names= []
next_marker = None
while True:
    blob_list = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container,  prefix='/curated/projects/IntelligentShipmentOptimization/',
                                    num_results=400, marker=next_marker)
    for blob in blob_list:
        names.append(blob.name)
    
    next_marker = blob_list.next_marker
    print(next_marker)
    if not next_marker:
        break
```