# How do I get all blobs at all levels in a container?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302487/python-azure-sdk-using-list-blobs-to-get-more-than-5-000-results) thread about listing the blobs in a container.

```
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<accountname>', account_key='<accountkey>')
next_marker = None
while True:
    blobs = blob_service.list_blobs('<containername>', maxresults=100, marker=next_marker)
    next_marker = blobs.next_marker
    print(next_marker)
    print(len(blobs))
    if next_marker is None:
        break
print "done"
```

However, that would only list the blobs in a specific container. How would I go about getting all the blobs in subfolders? I have several levels of subfolders, and I would like to get the names of all data files from the parent container.

Comment: What do you mean by subfolders? This should list all of the blobs within a container.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Azure SDK for Phython 2.7 or 3.4?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the blob containers and all blobs instead of    only blobs in a specific container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function `list_containers()` we can see at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L470 which purposes to get all the containers in your storage

```
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<account_name>', account_key='<account_key>')
containers = blob_service.list_containers()

for c in containers:
    print(c.name)
```

Then you can call list_blob method in the loop with the containers’ name.

Additionally, if you have several subfolders defined in blob names,  there is a thread [list virtual folders in azure blob storage via python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477687/list-virtual-folders-in-azure-blob-storage-via-python-api) on SO you can refer to.

Comment: This helped me but I could import `BlobService`, had to change for `BlockBlobService`

Comment: @BartC; same issue here. I can not import BlobService (neither after unsintalling Azure and reinstalling azure). How did you solved it with BlocbBlobService?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a little bit in the above-approved solution.
BlobService has been deprecated in the new version use BlockBlobService instead.

```
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<account_name>', account_key='<account_key>')
containers = blob_service.list_containers()

for c in containers:
    print(c.name)
```

Comment: This is good for listing all containers in a blob storage account, but how to list all blobs regardless of container and subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not working...

Below is the Python code using Microsoft **Azure SDK for Python 3.4** that will list the all the blob names (with the full "subfolder" path, e.g. project1/images/image1.png) in a specific container.

If you wish to get all the blob names in all the containers in a storage account, just do `blob_service.list_containers` to iterate through each container and list all blobs under each iteration.

This is also a useful article on how to use Azure Blob Storage from Python.

[How to use Azure Blob storage from Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage.md)

Hope this helps!

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<storage account name>', account_key='<storage account key>')

blobs = []
marker = None
while True:
    batch = blob_service.list_blobs('<blob container name>', marker=marker)
    blobs.extend(batch)
    if not batch.next_marker:
        break
    marker = batch.next_marker
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Comment: The code above will list all the blobs in a blob container. I believe the OP wants to list blobs in a sub folder inside a blob container.

Answer (score 0):

This is close, but I'm unsure of how to exclude folder names from the results. Also, I'm fairly sure this is hitting the storage account **very** hard.

Might want to be careful!

(Assumes you have the Connection String saved as the environment variable `conn_str`)

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


blob_svc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['conn_str'])

containers = blob_svc.list_containers()

list_of_blobs = []

for c in containers:
    container_client = blob_svc.get_container_client(c)
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blob_list:
        list_of_blobs.append(os.path.basename(blob.name))

print(len(list_of_blobs))
```

I was able to return 22k+ blob (and folder) names in ~65 secs.